# Tried to deposit two cheques at an ATM, forgot one of the cheques

Tags: check, deposits, atm

Realised just as the machine took the envelope that I was still holding the other cheque, but the deposit amounts that I typed into the ATM specify two cheques. Bank is closed so I took the other cheque back home, and asked this question. What happens now?

Comment: This happened to my wife. She received a letter indicating the amount entered was incorrect and was adjusted. No biggie.

Comment: I've done this before as well.  It took a couple of days for the bank to adjust the deposited amount but it was no big deal.  Then I deposited the other check.  (I'd imagine this is reasonably common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's not a big deal. They'll inform me that they amended the incorrect deposit sometime in the future.